# Ionic > Cannot find module 'ansi'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

Building an `Ionic` project on a mac, throws the following error: `Cannot find module 'ansi'`

**Command:** `ionic build android`

**Stacktrace**

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'ansi'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bob/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/CordovaLogger.js:20:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
Error: /Users/bob/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
```

**N.B.** Simply installing the missing module doesn't work (i.e. `npm install ansi`), as it complains about other missing modules...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the issue occurs (maybe someone can enlighten me), but removing and re-adding the `Android` platform fixes the issue.

i.e.

```
ionic platform remove android
ionic platform add android
```